# Calling a bash function with arguments stored in bash file script gives CalledProcessError in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, bash, function, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**My situation:**
I installed the bash_kernel with Conda and used it in a Jupyter Notebook environment. I run it from Gitbash. Cell magic "%%bash" works, executing scripts works, executing bash functions works.

Now I try to execute a script with a function with arguments stored in a bash file. Running this gives me the "CalledProcessError". It must have something to do with the arguments or not? I tried call argumens with and wihtout quotes, with ./  and so on. Nothing works.

**How do I solve the error?**

The code works if I execute it in a cell like this.

````
```%%bash
find(){
cat $1 | grep -e $2 -e $3
}
find "poetry/poe_raven.txt" "dreary" "weary"``
````

It gives the result:
dreary, while
weak and weary,

This is okay.
Now I write it into a Bash file. Alternatively I have used Notepad ++ with EOL and Line Splitting.

````
```
%%bash
echo "find(){" > find.bash
echo "cat \$1 | grep -e \$2 -e \$3" >> find.bash
echo "}" >> find.bash
echo "find" >> find.bash```

```

%%bash
cat find.bash
```

```
find(){
cat $1 | grep -e $2 -e $3
}
find```
````

Now I am trying to do the function call with arguments:

````
```
%%bash
./find.bash "poetry/poe_raven.txt" "dreary" "weary"
```
````

This gives the CalledProcessError:

> 

---

CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\GAMARA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22152/3531725088.py in 
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', './find.bash "poetry/poe_raven.txt" "dreary" "weary"\n')

...

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'./find.bash "poetry/poe_raven.txt" "dreary" "weary"\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `"poetry/poe_raven.txt"` is interpreted as string and therefore converted to `poetry/poe_raven.txt` without the `""`.

You could try: `./find.bash '"poetry/poe_raven.txt"' '"dreary"' '"weary"'`

Or shorter using f-string: `./find.bash f'"poetry/poe_raven.txt" "dreary" "weary"'`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This did not work for me. Any other suggestions?